# Azure - Deploy site to directory but use sub directory as site

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service, publish

I'd like to start by saying I am very (VERY) new to Azure. I have just publish an AngularJS app and I've come across an irritating issue.

When publishing the app from visual studio the first time around, it placed the files inside *site\wwwroot*. This was fine because I then just changed the virtual path to look at the *www* subfolder.

So the new setting makes */* equal to *site\wwwroot\www*

This is because the code for my site actually sits within this www folder. Everything worked! Great!

However, the next time I did a publish, the whole site was then places within *site\wwwroot\www*, meaning that to get to my index page I had to go to *site\wwwroot\www\www*.

For some reason by defining the 'Physical path relative to site root', it changes the whole publish path. This does kind of makes sense, but is there anyway around this issue? Possibly a different practice or setting I haven't come across yet.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mapped `/` to `site\wwwroot\www`, your later publish would be applied to `site\wwwroot\www`. Per my understanding, you could directly deploy your web content under `www` to `site\wwwroot` via ftp tools, etc. Or you could use [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) instead of changing the virtual path for `/`. And your rewrite rules under the `web.config` file as follows:

**web.config:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="hide www sub directory" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^www/(.*)"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="rewrite to sub directory">
          <match url="^(?!www)(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="www/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** The `we.config` file is under `site\wwwroot`.

**TEST:**

[Kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

[image]

For accessing the index.html, you need to access `https://brucewebapp.azurewebsites.net/www/index.html`. Using the url rewrite rules, you could just access `https://brucewebapp.azurewebsites.net/index.html` as follows:

[image]